# Resource warning: open file despite with open() as f syntax

Tags: python

I access all my file contents using the following syntax (example here for pickle):

```
with open(fp, 'rb') as f:
    pickle.load(f)
```

I've never had problems, until a couple of days ago where, for EACH file access, I get a `Resource warning: open file` warning:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.FileIO name='c:\\mypy\\code\\cafe3\\data\\BRIGHTWAY2_DIR\\cafe3dev.eecf880ed9423e61184dbec799fff6e4\\intermediate\\ilcd-108-2016-midpointcg.cbf193bf865269b0892e16e5183410f8.pickle' mode='rb' closefd=True>
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='c:\\mypy\\code\\cafe3\\data\\BRIGHTWAY2_DIR\\cafe3dev.eecf880ed9423e61184dbec799fff6e4\\intermediate\\ilcd-108-2016-midpointcg.cbf193bf865269b0892e16e5183410f8.pickle'>
```

This is also true for other types of files (e.g. saved numpy arrays (.npy), json...

What could possibly be going on?

Comment: disk full/failure maybe ? try another disk?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a [mcve]?